# ASP.NET Core 6 bundler choking on CSS a:has with child class

Tags: css, asp.net-core, asp.net-bundling

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 with legacy CSS code.

I added a new CSS block as follows:

```
.myclass a:has(i.other-class) {
  ...
}
```

The bundler is failing with error

> Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected identifier, found '.'.
>
> Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected comma or open brace, found ')'

I tried with many combinations as follows:

```
.myclass a:has(> i.other-class)  

.myclass:has(a):has(> i.other-class)
```

all failed

Comment: Did you mean to have `.myclass a:has(> i.other-class) {` or perhaps
`.myclass:has(a):has(> i.other-class) {` maybe just take out the `i`

Comment: Tried many
.myclass:has(a):has(> i.other-class)  
.myclass:has(a):has(> .other-class)

still the same. I will add these to my question

Comment: Might also outline the minifier in use re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-7.0#choose-a-bundling-and-minification-strategy

Comment: Actually I was wrong. taking out the "i" worked.

Thanks a lot.  feel free to add your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code for some options consider:

- `.myclass a:has(> i.other-class) {`
- or perhaps `.myclass:has(a):has(> i.other-class) {`
- maybe just take out the `i` so it uses the class i.e. `.myclass a:has(.other-class) {`

ON my STUMP: I don't really like CSS based on element names anyway since a `<span>` and an `<i>` can often be used interchangeably (and the span actually reflects a case where it should be used but was "hijacked" just because `i` is smaller/less text. (my IMHO) part - now I can jump off my stump speech.